# Testing for significance between two average slopes

Tags: regression, t-test

I have a question regarding my logic of how to go about checking for the significance between two average slopes. I hope my message comes across clear.

The data I am analyzing consists of two sets, each with 25 slope values (and a corresponding standard deviation) and 25 y-intercepts (with corresponding standard deviation).

I then average these slopes and y-intercepts, along with their corresponding standard deviations. Thus I get the average slopes and average standard deviations -- I actually average the variance(M1, M2, S1, S2).

How do I go about testing for significance between these average slope values?

I read: [Test a significant difference between two slope values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/test-a-significant-difference-between-two-slope-values), but this is for the case with simply two slopes. Can I perform the t-test as mentioned in the above link using the M1, M2, S1, S2 I calculated?