# Test a significant difference between more than two slope values

Tags: regression, statistical-significance

I have a follow-up question to this threat:

[Test a significant difference between two slope values](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/test-a-significant-difference-between-two-slope-values/55505#55505?newreg=b425015c26884aad9f25fed4e0bae337)

There is a formula introduced to calculate a z-score when testing for a significant difference between two slope values. I have succesfully applied the formula (thanks to the user Marloes).

Now my question: When I compare the slope values from more than two regressions, let's say three, and I use the formula three times, do I have to adjust the values because of alpha error accumulation?

I guess the answer should be "yes" because the basic problem of multiple comparisons in one set of data stays the same. But as I am not 100% sure, I'd be glad for some opinions.

Kind regards & thanks in advance
Seb