# R: How to test whether two means to effect sizes (mes) are significantly different?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, effect-size

To test one of my hypotheses, I want to show that the effect size A -> B is significanlty larger than C -> D using R.

So far, I've been using the `mes()` function from the `compute.es` package to calculate the effect sizes.

Let's say we have the following values:

```
Function: mes(mean1, mean2, sd1, sd2, n1, n2)
# Effect size 1: A -> B
mes(4.53, 5.57, 1.04, 0.70, 45, 47)
# Effect size 2: C -> D
mes(5.69, 6.12, 0.85, 0.57, 48, 48)
```

How can I show, that the effect size 1 is significantly larger than 2 using R?

Answer (score 4):

Fit two linear models to compute each effect, e.g.

```
m1 <- lm(B ~ A) #Here I am assuming the effect A -> B means A is influencing B
m2 <- lm(D ~ C)
```

Get the estimated effect sizes and their standard errors:

```
b1 <- coef(summary(m1))[2, 1]
b2 <- coef(summary(m2))[2, 1]
SEb1 <- coef(summary(m1))[2, 2]
SEb2 <- coef(summary(m2))[2, 2]
```

Calculate the $Z$-score for the difference:

```
Z <- (b1-b2)/sqrt(SEb1^2+SEb2^2)
```

And calculate the corresponding P-value:

```
2*pnorm(-abs(Z))
```

*Reference:* Marloes (https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/18334/marloes), Test a significant difference between two slope values, URL (version: 2013-04-09): https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/55505

Comment: For bonus points, can you rewrite as a function taking mod1, mod2 as arguments?

Comment: @smci something like [this](https://dumptext.com/8H7ChxXx).

Comment: Totally. I was suggesting posting the function as your answer. If the return-value is  p-value, I'd call the function ptest.lm.es or somesuch