# Statistically Compare Slopes of Linear Regressions from 2 Separate datasets

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, inference

I am currently working on several datasets which I want to statistically compare the slopes of 3 linear regressions made from 3 datasets. I am not necessarily interested in the r values at this point but specifically the slopes. I feel that I cannot combine the datasets as each of sets are subsections of a single larger data set which remove 0's when present. For example

```
Patch  Area   Rare_Count      Common_Count     Extreme_Count   
 A      10         0               20              25
 B      100        12              40              60
 C      50         10              30               0
 D      15         0               40              25
```

In this case I run the linear model to compare the effect of Area on each of the 3 Count measure. However generally 0 values are not included in such analysis although several experts believe it they should be. As I am trying to have comparable numbers to other analyses I was hoping to do it with 0's removed. Thus I would compare only patches B and C when I am interested in Area ~ Rare_Count. Which is why I do the analysis 3 times for each of the 3 counts with their respective subsetted datasets and then want to compare these slopes.

One option would be to go with the Z value derived using SE. See this [Answer with Z](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/55505). However I am not sure the appropriateness of this and how exactly to interpret such a Z value. For example if my slopes and their variance (which is their SEˆ2) were this:

```
Data <- data.frame(
ID = c(1:4),
Slope = c(0.26, 0.13, 0.14, 0.19),
Var = c(6.00E-05, 7.00E-05, 8.00E-05, 8.00E-05))
```

Would it be enough to simply calculate the Z value as described in the answer above:

Z= (slope1-slope2)/(sqrt(SE1ˆ2 +SE2ˆ2))

Z1:2= 0.26-0.13/sqrt(6e-5+7e-5)

Z1:2= 11.4

How would one interpret this?

Or am I way off base with this route and I actually need to go about this completely differently.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you explain "I cannot combine the datasets." A combined model would be the recommended and easiest approach.

Comment: Edited to explain why I don't feel that I can combine the datasets.