# How to compare 2 regression slopes with R?

Tags: r, regression

I have to compare the slopes of 2 regression lines with R. The 2 regressions are made with the same parameters in 2 different locations.

I did my regressions with the function lm(). Now I have the results but I don't know how to compare them..

I tried with student test or ANOVA but it requires more than the 2 slopes.

I looked for an answer during something like 2 hours but didn't find, so I ask the question here : How should I do my test?

Thank you in advance,
b.raoul

Comment: Try [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33013/what-test-can-i-use-to-compare-slopes-from-two-or-more-regression-models?rq=1) or [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/test-a-significant-difference-between-two-slope-values?rq=1) -- these cover the two main approaches.

Comment: ok thank you, I will see this but I'm affraid my knowledges in statistics won't be enough.. Can I make a student test with the 2 means and the st dev with the r.test function?

Comment: If you're able to identify what particular things you need to know to understand those answers and ask about those, perhaps in a new question, you might get somewhere. I'm not sure what else to suggest; CV isn't really an easy place to learn basic statistics, but mostly to overcome specific issues.

Comment: ok I will post my question in a more basic forum. Thank you for your answers

Comment: I don't wish to suggest that basic questions are unwelcome - that's not the case. It's simply that if there are many things you need to understand in order to comprehend the answers, it's not the appropriate place to get 'lessons'. If you can formulate what you need to know in terms of questions that can be answered, you can get there.