# Follow-up question on comparing predictor in regressions over two groups

Tags: r, regression, baseline

Using a [previous Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34295123/5044791) as a guide:

I have two groups and I want to see how changes in a variable are predicted by variable 'baseline'. And then I wanted to see if there are group differences in this prediction. Per previous threads to do this, I did something like:

```r
fm1 <- lm(change ~ baseline, DF)
fm3 <- lm(change ~ groups/(baseline - 1), DF)
```

And then a comparison of the models:

```r
anova(fm1, fm3)
```

I was wondering if someone could clarify what this comparison actually means. I guess we are comparing a model where equality of coefficients assumed (fm1) vs model where equality of coefficients is not assumed?

Answer (score 0):

First, an answer to how to interpret the models and comparison. Second, a warning based on the names you have chosen for your variables.

**First**:

> I guess we are comparing a model where equality of coefficients assumed (fm1) vs model where equality of coefficients is not assumed?

It's a little more complicated than that. Yes, model `fm1` assumes that the slope of the relationship is the same for all groups, but model `fm3` includes several extra coefficient estimates. I'll use the sample data from your [linked page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34295123/5044791) as an example, where there are 3 `age` groups and the regression is of `weight` on `height`.

```
DF
#   age height weight
# 1   1     56    140
# 2   1     60    155
# 3   1     64    143
# 4   2     56    117
# 5   2     60    125
# 6   2     64    133
# 7   3     74    245
# 8   3     75    241
# 9   3     82    269
DF$age <- as.factor(DF$age)
fm1 <- lm(weight ~ height, DF)
fm3 <- lm(weight ~ age/(height - 1), DF)
```

You can see the extra complexity by examining the regression coefficient estimates of the two models:

```
coef(fm1)
# (Intercept)      height 
# -226.891667    6.108333 
coef(fm3)
#        age1        age2        age3 age1:height age2:height age3:height 
#  123.500000    5.000000   -7.701754    0.375000    2.000000    3.368421
```

Model `fm1` has an Intercept (the estimated `weight` for the impossible situation when `height = 0`) and a single slope estimate (the `height` coefficient).

In model `fm3` you have separate estimates for each `age` group (implicitly for `height = 0` in each `group`). The `-1` in the formula for `fm3` omits the overall model intercept, so those `age` coefficients can be thought of as group-specific intercepts. (Although that works in this simple case, you should generally be very careful about omitting intercepts.) You also have separate slopes for `height` within each `group`, as desired.

The `anova()` comparison is whether the improvement in fit in model `fm3` is sufficiently better than that of `fm1` to make up for the extra 4 parameters that `fm3` must estimate.

I find the approaches in the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58775847/5044791) on the page you linked, and in the [Cross Validated page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/33013/28500) linked from that answer, to be superior and more generally useful in more complicated scenarios.

**Second**:

When I see `change` as an outcome and `baseline` as a predictor, I worry. See [this page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/15713/28500) for reasons why. You will generally be better off modeling the actual later outcome value instead of its `change`.